# Sound input settings not being saved?

Tags: 14.04, sound, logitech, input

I can't seem to get the input settings to save. Ubuntu knows that my mic is there. Here is the same problem that I am having: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Q9EQvLl_rA&feature=youtu.be

I have a Logitech G35 by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's my video, and sadly I never found a solution.  In fact, since upgrading to 14.10, even my desktop now has this issue.  In fact, all of my Ubuntu machines have this issue.  I made a bug report in launchpad, no help ever came of it, just useless support for the wrong solution that had nothing to do with the actual issue, and their forums is more like praise Ubuntu.

I'm switching to Debian, and if that fails, I might be ditching Linux entirely.  I've lost money because I do music recording on the side, and I've had now too many embarrassing moments when my computer can't even record.